# Is there a easy way to get the double level related_name instances in Django Queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have three models bellow:

```
class AModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=11)

class BModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    a = models.ForeignKey(AModel, related_name="bs")

class CModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    b = models.ForeignKey(BModel, related_name="cs")
```

If I have a AModel instance, if I want to get all the cmodel instances of it, I will use a forloop:

```
c_list = []
for b in a.bs:
    for c in b.cs:
        c_list.append(c)
```

But, whether there is a easy way to get all the cmodel instances of a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CModel.objects.filter(b__a__name='something')
```